# Change background color in Yii2 gridview cell depend on its value

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am trying to make background color that depending on the value calculation number in one cell. This is my code:

```
[
'attribute' => 'coefTK',
'label' => '<abbr title="Koefisien Jumlah Tenaga Kerja">TK</abbr>',
'encodeLabel' => false,
'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
'options' => [ 'style' => $dataProvider['coefTK']/$dataProvider['coefTK_se']<2 ? 'background-color:red':'background-color:blue'],
        ],
```

but i got an error, that say "Cannot use object of type yii\data\ActiveDataProvider as array"

So, How can i change the background gridview cell that have value from some calculation ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `contentOptions`:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'coefTK',
    'label' => '<abbr title="Koefisien Jumlah Tenaga Kerja">TK</abbr>',
    'encodeLabel' => false,
    'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align:center'],
    'contentOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return ['style' => 'background-color:' 
            . (!empty($model->coefTK_se) && $model->coefTK / $model->coefTK_se < 2
                ? 'red' : 'blue')];
    },
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rowOptions` and change the value of `class` to change the color.

```
'rowOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
    if($index % 2 == 0){
        return ['class' => 'info'];
    }
},
```

This will generate an output like the following:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

rowOptions add in Gridview

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'rowOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
        if($index % 2 == 1){
            return ['class' => 'info'];
        }
    },
    'columns' => [
    .........
```